# WeakReference in (Mono C#) staying alive even after GC.Collect

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection, xamarin.android, weak-references

The following piece of code written in C# and executed on Mono Droid, isn't working as expected.

```
    var strongRef = "abc";
    WeakReference weakRef = new WeakReference (strongRef);
    strongRef = null;
    System.GC.Collect (2,GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Target:" + weakRef.Target + " IsAlive:" + weakRef.IsAlive);
```

Expected O/P: Target:null IsAlive:false

Actual O/P: Target:abc IsAlive:true

Comment: If Mono works anything like .NET in this regard, `"abc"` is an interned string, it will *never* be collected.

Comment: Try `new object()` instead of a string.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski and @vcsjone. Replaced `abc` with `new Object()` still behaves the same

Comment: The problem was with the method stack. Found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417283/strange-weakreference-behavior-on-mono?rq=1)